# How to make colorPrimary not show as toolbar background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-toolbar

I am trying to make the toolbar background color transparent however, the colorPrimary theme seems to be showing  instead. When I set the background of the toolbar to a standard color, it overrides colorPrimary and work as intended, but is there a way for me to get rid of it completely as to make the toolbar background transparent? The reason that I still want colorPrimary is because of the recent apps tab color, I just want it to not show in the toolbar. Thank you.

[image]

### Toolbar

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

### Style

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: You don't want to show toolbar in activity? @Roderick Lord

Comment: I want the toolbar, but I want it transparent. The problem is that colorPrimary sets the toolbar color which I do not want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the code instead of only toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Have been looking to fix this issue since an hour. You saved my time. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_translucent" />
```

background_toolbar_translucent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="@color/black_alpha_40"/>
```

colors.xml

```
<color name="black_alpha_40">#66000000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

make **toolbar.xml** inside layout folder. Use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And use this toolbar in your activity's xml. This way you will have a  transparent toolbar.